# Error al condicionar en ciclo do while

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando hacer un formulario mediante JOptionPane, que el usuario tiene que llenar para  emitir una factura. Tengo que hacer que al final del ciclo, el programa le pregunte al usuario si desea emitir una factura, y dada su respuesta, que se repita el ciclo o no. Pero tengo un error al momento de colocar la condición en el While, y no sé que hacer. ¡Gracias!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Practica4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int inicio = 0;
        String[] articulos = {
            "CPU",
            "RAM",
            "GPU",
            "Disco Duro",
            "Fan Cooler",
            "Tarjeta madre",
            "Teclado",
            "Mouse",
            "Monitor",
            "Fuente de poder"
        };
        do  {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido/a al sistema de facturación. Por favor, ingrese sus datos personales");
        int cedula = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cédula:"));
        String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombres y apellidos:");
        String direccion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dirección:");
        int telefonoR = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Teléfono residencial:"));
        int telefonoM = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Teléfono móvil:"));
        
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Seleccione el producto que desea adquirir:", "Lista de artículos", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, articulos, articulos[0]);
        int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Qué cantidad desea?"));
        
        int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea emitir otra factura?");
        
        } while (resp = 0)
   
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En la línea del while estás poniendo una asignación cuando deberías poner una comparación. Prueba cambiando

```
while(resp = 0)
```

Por

```
while(resp == 0)
```

Espero te ayude

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, Gerardo. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Si consideras que la respuesta de Emiliano ha sido válida podrías marcarla como tal en el visto verde que tienes al lado de su respuesta. De nuevo bienvenido y un saludo.